# How to Optimize below query

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

```
SELECT
    t1.theater_id,
    sum(t2.full_sale_price * t1.full_tickets + 
        t2.half_sale_price * t1.half_tickets) as Gross,
    sum(t2.full_cost_price * t1.full_tickets +
        t2.half_cost_price * t1.half_tickets) as Cost,
    Round(sum((t2.full_sale_price * t1.full_tickets + 
               t2.half_sale_price * t1.half_tickets) * t3.rate) / 100,
         2) as IPG,
         (sum(t2.full_sale_price * t1.full_tickets + 
              t2.half_sale_price * t1.half_tickets) 
              - Round(sum((t2.full_sale_price * t1.full_tickets + 
              t2.half_sale_price * t1.half_tickets) * (CASE
                WHEN ISNULL(t3.rate) THEN 0
                ELSE t3.rate
                END)) / 100,
            2)) as NetRev,
    CASE
        WHEN (t1.method = '2') THEN sum(0.00)
        ELSE 0
    END as sms,
    sum((CASE
        WHEN (t4.type = '1') THEN ((t1.full_tickets * 2) + (t1.half_tickets))
        ELSE (t1.full_tickets + t1.half_tickets)
    END) * 4.00) as maintenance,
    sum((((t2.full_sale_price * t1.full_tickets + 
           t2.half_sale_price * t1.half_tickets) 
           - (Round((t2.full_sale_price * t1.full_tickets + 
                     t2.half_sale_price * t1.half_tickets) * (CASE
                WHEN ISNULL(t3.rate) THEN 0
                ELSE t3.rate
            END) / 100,
            2))) - (t2.full_cost_price * t1.full_tickets + 
                    t2.half_cost_price * t1.half_tickets)) 
                    - (CASE
                       WHEN (t1.method = '2') THEN 0.00
                       ELSE 0
                       END) 
                    - (CASE
                       WHEN (t4.type = '1') THEN ((t1.full_tickets * 2) +
                                                  (t1.half_tickets))
                       ELSE (t1.full_tickets + t1.half_tickets)
    END) * 4.00) as admincost,
    sum(CASE
        WHEN (t4.type = '1') THEN ((t1.full_tickets * 2) + (t1.half_tickets))
        ELSE (t1.full_tickets + t1.half_tickets)
    END) as totTk
FROM
    `ratecard_rates` as t2 INNER JOIN
    `reservation` as t1 ON t1.movie_id = t2.movie_id
        AND t1.theater_id = t2.theater_id
        AND t1.showtime_id = t2.showtime_id
        AND t1.category_id = t2.category_id
        AND t1.bx_date = t2.date_apply
        LEFT JOIN
    `paymentgateway` as t3 ON t1.paymentgateway_id = t3.id
        LEFT JOIN
    `theatercategories` as t4 ON t1.category_id = t4.id
WHERE
    t1.status = '1' AND t1.method = '1'
        AND t1.reservation_type = '1'
        AND DATE(`tx_date`) BETWEEN DATE('2012-08-27') AND DATE('2012-08-27')
GROUP BY t1.theater_id
```

Here is the EXPLAIN 
[image: EXPLAIN]

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: i did indexing, didn't work for me

Comment: Is it necessary to keep it in one query?

Comment: noh! do whatever you can and tell me

Comment: Often in my work, the best way to optimize large query is divided into several smaller your queries

Comment: `CASE WHEN ISNULL(t3.rate) THEN 0 ELSE t3.rate END` == `IFNULL(t3.rate, 0)` I think it is better readable.

Comment: is there anyone that can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"Using temporary; using filesort"` usually means that at this point in the query plan, MySsql decides to write an interim set to disk, which unfortunately means it is not always able to use an index you might have placed on the relevant column.

The only way to get around this, in my experience, is to try and reduce the set size for interim results. Try and isolate the point at which this occurs: for example: replace your whole `SELECT` with a `COUNT(*)` to eliminate the CASE bits etc. and see what is producing the 2779 rows which MySql wants to "cache" on disk.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1092009/110933) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Did you indexed blindly or you first checked you execution plan? `CASE..END` clause helps a lot but can mess a lot the execution plan sometimes. Check [this link](http://jahaines.blogspot.com.es/2010/05/performance-tuning-case-expressions.html) it can help you to understand what I'm talking about. One option is creating a stored procedure and splitting this query on smaller querys. Sometimes subqueries can be helpfull, that is another option to try out.

Comment: that's a good link, but it specifically refers to CASE with subqueries, which is not what's happening here.

Comment: I agree with you, but I'm not pointing out the link as a solution, but as an example of how the `CASE..END` can mess up the execution plan.

Comment: yes, but it can't mess up the plan when it is not forcing a change to the plan. CASE + subquery: yes, the plan can/will be changed: CASE + simple aritmetic: no it won't. Even with the CASE inside a sum: you're looking at rows that have already been isolated by the GROUP statement.

Comment: Thanks! let me try and get back to you